# Is there a new function type expression format in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-prototypes

Today I checked out [Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) (modified April 7, 2013) and saw this at the end of the type-alias section:

```
typedef void (*PFD)(double);    // C style
using PF = void (*)(double);    // using plus C-style type
using P = [](double)->void;     // using plus suffix return type
```

where a lambda introducer is used to start a general function type expression that uses a suffix-style return type.  Is this official, or a dropped beta/wish-list feature?  If it's official, how would it work for non-static member functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using P = [](double)->void;
```

is not official. Bjarne is known to be a bit careless in his FAQs.

What does work, however, are the following:

```
using P1 = auto(double) -> void;
using P2 = auto(*)(double) -> void;
```

Where `P1` is a function type, and `P2` is a function-pointer type. Maybe that was his intention.

Comment: So Bjarne's third entry is exploiting the stateless-lambda=to=regular-function conversion, right?  Right before reading this, I experimented and found that "`auto (MyClass::*)(Whatever) CV -> ReturnType`" works.

Comment: @CTMacUser: No it doesn't. `using` expects a type, `[](stuff)->stuff` is an incomplete lambda object. And yes, that's the syntax, just like a normal member-function-pointer, except with a trailing return type.